# How to change font for all subsequent plots in R?

Tags: r, fonts, plot, histogram, par

I know how to specify font for a concrete plot, but is there a way to specify it once for all subsequent plots, histograms etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `par`. In the following example, I assume you want to change the `family` setting but refer to `?par` for an exhaustive list of graph parameters you can change:

```
old.params <- par(family = "mono")

plot(cars)
hist(islands)
```

When done, you can reset everything to the old defaults:

```
par(old.params)
```